# NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified) with Paypal with CURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I have paypal payment API integrated, From today its showing me error like **NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)**. I have tried few solutions available here but not able to sort it out.

We have OPEN SSL enable on the server and using CentOs 6.x. Try to upgrade the OS again the same result.

We are on sandbox mode and running our server on IP as our domain yet to map. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass following parameters in `Curl` call if you are using `Curl`. Plus take care if you have any extra space in `json` data.

something like this:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, CARD_DATA_OBJECT);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer ".PAYPAL_TOKEN));
```

Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: I am having the same issue  NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified). After using your code getting the same thing. any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: I think your answer may be work on sandbox but NSS is related to certification. Should I have to the configuration anything on hosting server for make the transaction working in live Paypal Account.

Comment: @BhavdipSagar yea you have to upgrade your php and Curl version as well, because PayPal has change his Handshake policy to other domains. It demands TLS and Openssl with Curl, if you are using NSS then it won't work anymore.